# A drop down/minimizable PARAGTAPHS/text box in HTML

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a drop down paragraph for my website.
It is similar to a drop down menu but a whole paragraph

with centering and a font. I have seen a number of drop down menu's but they don't seem to support large text. The idea would be for a bar say:

===click here to read about====

and when you click it the paragraph will pop out underneath.
The plan is to have a few of them in order. This is to save website space.

So minimizeable paragraphs in HTML

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please pose specific questions about specific problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came upon your post looking for the same.
Here are some that are very nice that I have tried in case others come upon this post also:
'Pure CSS read more toggle': (with a clickable button as per your request): https://codepen.io/Idered/pen/AeBgF
'Readmore.js': http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/

And the one I went with:
'jQuery Read More/Less Toggle': https://codepen.io/maxds/pen/jgeoA
Some notes for the Read more/less for beginners (me):
1. The codepen exported zip file contains two sets of closing body and html tags.
2. html code counts as characters when setting how many characters to display in Show less box (index.js). Less by 6. After last text it will add: ...
3. In html inserting a !--comment after: span class="more" breaks it, at least for me.
4. To change link color of Show more/less for example in css:

```
a.morelink:link {color:#58534d; TEXT-DECORATION: none}
a.morelink:visited {color:#58534d; TEXT-DECORATION: none}
a.morelink:active {color:#f5f5dc; TEXT-DECORATION: none}
a.morelink:hover {color:#f5f5dc; TEXT-DECORATION: none}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Configure/customize these variables.
    var showChar = 100;  // How many characters are shown by default
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Show more >";
    var lesstext = "Show less";
    

    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
 
        if(content.length > showChar) {
 
            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
 
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
 
            $(this).html(html);
        }
 
    });
 
    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.morecontent span {
    display: none;
}
.morelink {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery Read More/Less Toggle Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="more">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <div class="more">
      Morbi placerat imperdiet risus quis blandit. Ut lobortis elit luctus, feugiat erat vitae, interdum diam. Nam sit amet arcu vitae justo lacinia ultricies nec eget tellus. Curabitur id sapien massa. In hac <a href="#">habitasse</a> platea dictumst. Integer tristique leo consectetur libero pretium pretium. Nunc sed mauris magna. Praesent varius purus id turpis iaculis iaculis. Nulla <em>convallis magna nunc</em>, id rhoncus massa ornare in. Donec et feugiat sem, ac rhoncus mauris. Quisque eget tempor massa.
    </div>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently was looking to do the same thing and discovered the magic word within a Weebly add-on: Accordion. There is a tutorial on this at W3 as well. I haven't tried it yet, but it may save others the trouble of finding workarounds, as you all seem to have. I didn't have the patience so I went looking for "drop-down faq" menu, which was what they had in Weebly (but you have to pay after you use a few lines, and then it's not as easy to style as you like), and was led to/reminded it was called "accordion." Hope it helps some of you! https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Answer (score 0):

It works similar to other drop-down menus just with a paragraph inside. I made a jsfiddle about it: https://jsfiddle.net/nypo1qeu/

You can find the code here too:

```
<div class="Dropdown">
    <button id="DropDown-Button">Hover me</button>
        <div class="Dropdown-Menu">
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
        </div>
```

```
.Dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
#Dropdown-Button {
    position: relative; 
    display: block;
}

.Dropdown-Menu {
    display: none;
    background-color: green;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.Dropdown:hover .Dropdown-Menu{
    display: block;
}
```

Let me explain the code for you:

I created a div container which is responsible for the trigger of the menu. If you hover over it, it shows you the paragraph.

The Button is just the graphical companion to the `<div>` trigger.

The second `<div>` container is responsible for the code which is kept in it. At default, it has the `display: none` property, but if you hover over the button, it gets the `display: block` property and you can see it.

Simple huh?

I hope I could help you. If you need more help, just ask. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, the only other adjustment would be for it to be clickable not hover able.

Comment: That's great, it only needs to be clickable now thank you very much for going over it for me with explaining the code and what it does (It's always good to hear it from a person who know's instead of being self taught and believing that you understand a tutorial).

Comment: Okay, for the clickable drop down I have managed to get this http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_right working but now I am stuck trying to make more than one working drop down menu, argh

Comment: Can you share your current code at jsfiddle with me?

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your help. What I managed to was use the code and tutorial from this link to help http://www.htmldog.com/techniques/dropdowns/

I was able to edit and chop and change. It was annoying because upper case transform was on so I got rid of it and you can play with making the drop downs absolute and copying and pasting the CSS but renaming it main_nav2 or something that way they don't overlap each other with the drop downs.

That way you can hover over it and the text will appear and you can make the drop down box a different colour. Its drop down now but I want it clickable

css:
            #main_nav ul {
            background: #f84445;
            max-width: ;
            float: left;
            -webkit-transition: .5s;
            transition: .5s;
        }

```
    #main_nav li {
float: left;
position: relative;
width: 450px;
list-style: none;
-webkit-transition: .5s;
transition: .5s;
inline-box-align:last
    }

    #main_nav > ul > li > a, h1 {
        text-transform: ;
    }

    #main_nav a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        color: #000;
    }

    #main_nav ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 100%;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    #main_nav ul ul ul {
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }

    #main_nav li:hover, #main_nav li:hover li {
        background: #ddd;
    }

    #main_nav li li:hover, #main_nav li li:hover li {
        background: #bbb;
    }

    #main_nav li li li:hover {
        background: #999;
    }

    #main_nav li:hover > ul {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

and html

```
<div ="left">
   <tr>
     <td><p>&nbsp;</p>
       <nav id="main_nav"></nav>
       <section id="main_content"></section>
       <nav id="main_nav">
         <p>&nbsp;</p>
         <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
         <p><br>
         </p>
             <div align="center"><em>1</em>
               <ul>
                 <li> </li>
               </ul>
        </div>
             <ul>
               <li>
                 <p align="center"><a href=""><br />
                1 one/won.</a></p>
                 <p align="center"><a href=""><br />
                 </a></p>
               </li>
             </ul>
      </li>
         </ul>
         <ul>
           <li>
             <div align="center"><em>2</em>
               <ul>
            <li> </li>
               </ul>
             </div>
             <ul>
               <li>
                 <p align="center"><a href="">
                   2. Two, too or to</a></p>

               </li>
             </ul>
           </li>
         </ul>
         <ul>
           <li>
             <div align="center"><em>3</em>
               <ul>
                 <li> </li>
               </ul>
             </div>
             <ul>
               <li>
                 <p align="center"><a href=""><br />
                  3, three or free</p></a>
               </li>
             </ul>
           </li>
         </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a brilliant and efficient solution from Paul Obrien for a clickable dropdown paragraph.  Only feature missing is to change the label text after a click.  Anybody know how to make that magic happen?

https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/tpmAi

```
    label {
display:block;
margin:20px 0 0;
border-bottom:1px solid green;
}
label:hover { text-decoration:underline }
input {
position:absolute;
left:-999em
}
.hide {
width:50%;
border:1px solid #000;
background:red;
max-height:99em;
opacity:1;
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
transition:opacity 1.5s linear, max-height 1.5s linear;
}
.hide p {
padding:10px;
margin:0
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + div {
opacity:0;
max-height:0;
border:none;

}
.follow{border-top:1px solid blue;margin:0}
```

html:

```
<div>
    <label for="item-1">Toggle Div</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="one" id="item-1">
    <div class="hide">
            <p>Equation billions upon billions! Courage of our questions decipherment, take root and flourish, cosmic ocean paroxysm of global death. Light years inconspicuous motes of rock and gas from which we spring something incredible is waiting to be known, muse about!</p>
            <p>Equation billions upon billions! Courage of our questions decipherment, take root and flourish, cosmic ocean paroxysm of global death. Light years inconspicuous motes of rock and gas from which we spring something incredible is waiting to be known, muse about!</p>
    </div>
    <p class="follow">Following content</p>
```